# Deserializing different JSON payload from same Kafka topic with Spring Kafka- Syncronous

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi I am trying to consume two different json payloads from single topic and I am using different containerFactory.

It works for one payload and not working for other below is my sample code can anyone help me on this.

```
import request.DocumentContentRequest;
import response.DocumentContentResponse;

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.request}", containerFactory = "documentServiceRequestReplyListenerContainerFactory")


@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.ecm.request}", containerFactory = "requestReplyListenerContainerFactory")

public class KafkaConsumer {

LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);
    @KafkaHandler
    @SendTo("${kafka.topic.reply}")
    public PERequest receive(PERequest perequest) {
        System.out.println("Received request::"+perequest.toString());

        return perequest;
    }
    @KafkaHandler
    @SendTo("${kafka.topic.reply}")
    public DocumentContentRequest receive(DocumentContentRequest documentRequest) {
        System.out.println("Received request::"+documentRequest.toString());


        return documentRequest;
    }


}
```